# Navigation buttons crashes wpf program

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

I am using ribbons on wpf and as I switch tabs I use the SelectionChanged property and navigate to a different page. That works fine until I use the navigation back button and it all crashes.

The code below is replicated over the Page 2 and Page 3.

```
private void Ribbon_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var _currentSelection = Ribbon.SelectedIndex;
            if(_currentSelection != 0)
            {
                switch(_currentSelection)
                {
                    case 0:
                        NavigationService One = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
                        One.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/One.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        NavigationService Two = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
                        Two.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/Two.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        NavigationService Three = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
                        Three.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/Three.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I be able to navigate back to the previous page without the program crashing?

Is there a walk around solution that works?

Comment: How are you implementing your navigation back button?

Comment: The standard WPF navigation buttons at the top left corner of the screen, Back and forward buttons. Automatically comes up from when navigation is used (as code above is triggered). I havent implemented anything other than what I have done above

Comment: Do you really need goback? That's a rare requirement in wpf apps. Also. There are significant downsides to using frame and pages. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-do-not-use-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Comment: I think that you could have _previousSelectrion property, in which you could hold Ribbons selectedIndex and change it after each change.
Are you doing something like that and have a problem?

Comment: @RubenMartirosyan yes that is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: @RubenMartirosyan Do you have an example on how to do that?